standard__LightningInstrumentation is not available in assigned apps in Profile
I am facing similar issue like Error: no CustomApplication named standard__LightningInstrumentation found
If I simply remove the tag from the Profile metadata for standard__LightningInstrumentation, the build gets successful.
But when I checked in Production org, I am able to see the standard__LightningInstrumentation in the Assigned Apps in profiles.
But standard__LightningInstrumentation not available in the target org for which I am running the bulid.
If I can make the standard__LightningInstrumentation app available in the Assigned Apps, this issue can be resolved without making any change in profile metadatas.
Does anyone have any idea how to make standard__LightningInstrumentation visible in the Assigned Apps in profiles in Salesforce org?

This is, what I see looking under "Assigned Apps" at some org:

Lightning Usage App (standard__LightningInstrumentation)

The linked question "Error: no CustomApplication named standard__LightningInstrumentation found" fails to state the most important point, because it was slightly ahead of its time: standard__LightningInstrumentation is "Lightning Usage App", and this app is not available on Sandboxes - see Kris Goncalves' answer here (there is even an Idea on IdeaExchange). It's available on scratch orgs however. (What type of org is your target org?)
You can't install this standard app on your org. Either you have it or you don't. It depends on the type of your org.
